# Installation didn't complete and dpkg is now stuck

Tags: apt, dpkg

While installing openvpn running:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa
```

the command remained unfinished for hours. I finally decided to kill the terminal and reboot. 
OpenVPN is working but I can't install anything else. I keep getting an error that suggests to run the following command manually:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This command remains stuck for hours "Setting up openvpn (2.4.3-4ubuntu1) ..."

How could I fix this?

Comment: This is a total guess so take it with a grain of salt you can try `sudo apt-get install -f` it wont hurt anything but it may fix what the issue is.... but again .. its a total guess

Comment: are you getting any sort of errors ... anything that could suggest why its hanging?  have you looked at `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see if that gives you something to look for

Comment: I finally figured out that openvpn was already running ... I shut it down and ran: "sudo dpkg --configure -a" .This time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that openvpn was already running ... I shut it down and ran:

sudo dpkg --configure -a

This time it worked.